# User Beanshell processor to write code so that data driven testing performed rather than using csv

Tags: jmeter

I want to test a Get Request with list of values. I dont want to use CSV ,

so i started using Beanshell Preprocessor  and has those values in Array. Then used for loop to use those values and send to Get Request in HTTP Request. Every this was Successful except sending values to Get request. It is reading all values and sending the last read value to Get request.

Question : I want my request to run for each value when code reads the data one by one.

```
                var TtValuedetails;
                int i;
                n=22;
                String[] ttvalue = {"34324324224","fdadsfadsf","dfdsfdsfds","dafadsfa", 
                "45435435","dfadsfads"
                  };
          for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
           {
    
            if(i==0)
            {
                TtValuedetails=ttvalue[i];
                    
            if(ttvalue[0]=="34324324224")
                { 
                    vars.put("TtValuedetails",TtValuedetails);
                    log.info(TtValuedetails);
                    log.info("first value is executed" );
                    Org.Apache.......startRequest();
                }
            }
}   ;
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you without seeing the full code and knowing what you're trying to achieve but one thing is obvious: you should not be using Beanshell, [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use Groovy for scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead/).

Current problem with your code is:

- `ttvalue` array contains 6 elements
- `n=22`
- the line `TtValuedetails=ttvalue[i];` will cause failure on 7th iteration of the loop due to [IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

If you want to send a request for each value of the `ttvalue` array the easiest is converting it into separate [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

```
ttvalue_1=34324324224
ttvalue_2=fdadsfadsf
etc.
```

and using [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) for iterating the values.

Example Groovy code for storing the values into JMeter Variables:

```
String[] ttvalue = ["34324324224", "fdadsfadsf", "dfdsfdsfds", "dafadsfa",
                    "45435435", "dfadsfads"];

for (int i = 1; i <= ttvalue.size(); i++) {
    vars.put("ttvalue_" + i, ttvalue[i - 1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you response and may need more help on above question .. It would be great if you help me in this 

"JSR233 sampler" and "ForEachContorller" not sure .. why request under "ForEachContorller" is not executing

Placed "JSR233 sampler" then created "ForEachContorller --> Request" 

In ForEachContorller --> "Input VariablePrefix" as "${TtValuedetails_1}" and "Output Variable  Name"  as "TtValuedetails_new" 

"TtValuedetails_new" provided as variable in request.

Comment: Input variable prefix: `TtValuedetails`. Variable in request: `${TtValuedetails_new}` You can see all variables with their values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/). Official [documentation on the ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) is quite comprehensive

Comment: hoo sorry i saw your response now.. I already used debug sampler and seeing the values but my issue is foreach controller is not  executing .
in debug sampler 
TtValuedetails_1=34324324224
TtValuedetails_2=fdadsfadsf
TtValuedetails_3=dfdsfdsfds
TtValuedetails_4=dafadsfa
TtValuedetails_5=45435435
TtValuedetails_6=dfadsfads

Thread
  -->  JSR223Sampler ( vars.put("TtValuedetails_"+i , ttvalue[i - 1]);
   --> ForEachController
            -->  HTTPRequest( GET)
           --> DebugSampler

I used same as you said in above comment but still Foreach loop is not executed :(